# git asking for HTTPS username/pass even though remote is ssh

Tags: ssh, git

I've tried all solutions to this that I've come across but none of them appear applicable.

My remote is definitely, 100% ssh:

```
r        ssh://ubuntu@r/home/ubuntu/r (fetch)
r        ssh://ubuntu@r/home/ubuntu/r (push)
```

I can clone from the repo and ssh in without being prompted for a password. My `.ssh/config` is correct:

```
Host    r
    Hostname        r
    IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/arkadiy-r.pem
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    User ubuntu
```

I have verified that the server accepts the key:

```
Accepted publickey for ubuntu from xx.xx.xx.xx port 58761 ssh2: RSA fi:ng:er:pr:in:tt
debug1: monitor_child_preauth: ubuntu has been authenticated by privileged process
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug1: PAM: establishing credentials


User child is on pid 1514
debug1: SELinux support disabled
debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 1000/1000
debug1: packet_set_postauth: called
debug1: Entering interactive session for SSH2.
debug1: server_init_dispatch_20
debug1: server_input_channel_open: ctype session rchan 0 win 2097152 max 32768
debug1: input_session_request
debug1: channel 0: new [server-session]
debug1: session_new: session 0
debug1: session_open: channel 0
debug1: session_open: session 0: link with channel 0
debug1: server_input_channel_open: confirm session
debug1: server_input_global_request: rtype no-more-sessions@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request env reply 0
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req env
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request exec reply 1
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req exec
Starting session: command for ubuntu from xx.xx.xx.xx port 58761
```

But it still prompts me for an HTTPS (???) username/pass:

```
[master//mr]% git push r master        (arkadiy@helium:..ine/r/)
Username for 'https://r':
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your user name is 'Arkadiy'

If this is just for a single repo, you can set a username by going to the repo root and typing

```
git config user.name "Arkadiy"
```

If you want to set it for your entire computer type, anywhere in the command window:

```
git config --global user.name "Arkadiy"
```

Comment: `user.name` is set on both machines in the global git config

Comment: To clarify: I don't think this has anything to do with the issue above, and supplying a username either in this way or by entering it at the prompt doesn't have any effect